# An antonym for "what you might have assumed"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

It is right on the tip of my tongue, and I have searched the online thesauruses but I can't come up with it. What's the word that could fill in the blank:

> He came to the ***_*__** conclusion that you must be willing to serve if you want to truly lead.

The best I could come up with is "non-intuitive", but that just doesn't sound right. I know there's a better one. I want a word that means "this is not what you would expect", "this goes against your intuition". Something that approaches "nonsensical" or "irrational" but without the disparaging overtones, yet more forceful than "surprising".

Comment: _Surprising_? _Unexpected_? Ah, ***Counter***-_intuitive,_ that's it.

Comment: [@john lawler](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler): bingo! you got it! Submit that as an answer & I'll accept it.

Comment: Are we to guess the word in your mind or what?

Comment: @john lawler guessed it (and knew it when he got it): "Counter-intuitive". (I knew I was close, I just couldn't come up with it).

Comment: Good. It felt right. You got the answer, so that's good enough for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[Counterintuitive](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/counter-intuitive)* ("Contrary to intuition or common sense"), as one word rather than hyphenated, is appropriate.  (The hyphenated form is an accepted variant.)

After I thought of this word, I noticed John Lawler already mentioned it in a comment.  Oh well.

Other possibilities are *[contrary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contrary)* ("opposed in nature") and *[contrarian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contrarian)* ("a person who expresses a contradicting viewpoint, especially one who denounces the majority persuasion"), with the latter noun used adjectively.

Comment: Yes, indeed that was the word I was looking for. John Lawler already suggested it in his comment to the original post. But if he doesn't post it as an answer, I'll select yours.

Comment: Somewhere I read, "Just because an idea is counter-intuitive doesn't prove that it's true."

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is "paradoxical" or "seemingly paradoxical".

Comment: Very good. I like it.

Answer (score 2):

*[Astounding](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/astounding)*?

> : causing astonishment or amazement

He came to the **astounding** conclusion that you must be willing to serve if you want to truly lead.

Comment: "Astounding" seems ok, but for present purpose, I prefer "startling" to "astounding"

Answer (score 0):

`Unintuitive` feels right to me.

> He came to the *unintuitive* conclusion that you must be willing to serve if you want to truly lead.

If not, `obscure` seems also like a fair fit.

Comment: Hmm, that's actually the word I started with. But I still think there's another (even more common) one just around the corner...

Comment: Also, unintuitive isn't in the [MW dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unintuitive).

Comment: How's `obscure` then? That was my second choice :)

Comment: No, "obscure" doesn't have the element of surpising and unexpected that I need. I want something that means almost "flabbergasting". "I never would have guessed"

Comment: Dang, counter-intuitive seems so... intuitive too :)

Comment: No way! Results from Google Books for *the X conclusion* - [counterintuitive](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+counterintuitive+conclusion%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):3070, [counter-intuitive](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+counter+intuitive+conclusion%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):801, [unintuitive](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+unintuitive+conclusion%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):8. MW notwithstanding, OED lists *unintuitive* - but it means ***not** intuitive*, rather than ***contradicting** intuition*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers interesting- thank you! Perhaps there's some regional difference in the usage though. I know many of my professors used "unintuitive" most often for this context, but the OP is right in going with counterintuitive.

Comment: @professors: Are your professors native English speakers? Maybe they teach computer-related subjects - I don't think it's necessarily weird to speak of, say, *"an unintuitive user interface"* to mean one which isn't actually intuitive, but doesn't actively *thwart* intuitive expectations. I'll also point out that of the eight instances I found in GB, two are duplicates, and at least one is clearly by a non-native speaker. It's not really a usage I'd expect to hear from educated speakers, let alone those charged with educating others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're exactly correct on the computer-related subjects. In fact "unintuitive interface" was the particular phrase that popped into my mind when writing it. I guess its not so much region-specific but subject.

Answer (score 0):

Near Antonyms: authentic, bona fide, real, realistic, right, true; honest, ingenuous, sincere, unpretending; easy, effortless, smooth; extemporaneous, impromptu, impulsive, instinctive, unconscious, unprompted, unrehearsed, unstudied

Antonyms: artless, genuine, natural, spontaneous, unaffected, uncontrived, unfeigned, unforced

Answer (score -1):

I would use the words: ambiguous, enigmatic, equivocal, indistinct, nonobvious, obfuscated, unapparent, or even Ironic.